# Wordpress Search Button Vertical Aligning not Horizontal

Tags: html, wordpress, slider, search-form

I'm trying to get the Search Form Hero to look like this:

https://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-search-form-hero/

But the search button is always below the input field like this:

http://cheeky.travel/landing-2/

My hunch is it has something to do with vertical-align but not sure. This is the HTML:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="revtp-searchform"        action="https://cheeky.travel"><input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="What are you looking for?" /><input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" /><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" ></form>
```

Any ideas? I've tried to use span and row and nothing changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add `float:left` to the input field.